# Python stops with thread after time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I have a program with 2 simultanous threads with While True loops.
After a while one of the threads stops without a reason.
This is the code that starts the threads.

```
t = Thread(target=bg, args=(1,))
t.start()
t2 = Thread(target=vid, args=(1,))
t2.start()
```

Could someone help me with this.

PS: I'm running this python program on a raspberry pi

Comment: We need to see more code to see why these threads *stop without a reason*.

Comment: add try/except blocks to the functions and log any exceptions.